# How to copy contents of test file which is on server into an array

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am almost done with my music player. I am able to read my file which contains song_name and its url which is on the Server but dont know how to store these info into array song_name[] and song_url[] respectively. This is my complete code and the link is inside the code.

```
package com.hiphop.streamingmediaplayer;i
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Jsonmedia extends Activity {
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    Button play;
    String song_url[], song_name[];

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jsonview);

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://reallifethug.webs.com/temp_list.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            song_url = s.nextLine();
        }
        s.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // there was some connection problem, or the file did not exist on
        // the server,
        // or your URL was not in the right format.
        // think about what to do now, and put it here.
        ex.printStackTrace(); // for now, simply output it.
    }

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                mp.setDataSource(song_url);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.jsonmedia, menu);
    return true;

}
```

}

Comment: How the song name and song url's are formatted in temp_list.txt?

Comment: "Song_Name"<Space>"Song_URL"
For instance the File on the Server represents the format

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a List and push new elements into it

```
private String List<String> song_url;
private String List<String> song_name;


//inside the onCreate method

song_url = new ArrayList<>();
song_name = new ArrayList<>();

while (s.hasNextLine()) {
   //instead of this
   //song_url = s.nextLine();
   String newUrl = s.nextLine();

   song_url.add(newUrl);
}
```

But please note that this is only going to correctly save a new song url if song names are listed in every new lines.

Comment: I dont see `push` method in `List`

Comment: @sanbhat I am sorry, it is actually .add. I was working with a different language today and it got me confused =D...

Comment: @sanbhat you could also edit my answer instead of just down voting it =D

Comment: What about song_name, how to store data in this array?

Comment: Just make a Sound object, which contains a name and a path.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `Map<String,String>` to store the song names and song urls.

and the code for that is,

```
Map<String,String> songMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    line = s.nextLine();
    String[] songArr = line.split("\\s"); // assuming you have split name and url by space
    songMap.put(songArr[0], songArr[1]);
}
```

**Why map?**

With map, its easy to relate a Song name with a Song URL

```
songMap.get(songName);// gets the URL for that song
```

If you want to list all song URLs

```
for(String songUrl : songMap.values()) {
      //access individual songUrl
}
```

If you want to list all song names

```
for(String songName : songMap.keySet()) {
    //access individual songName
}
```

You can use `TreeMap` to maintain the sorted data-structure

The only limitation of using `Map` is you **cannot have duplicate** song names (which is key).